# Circled inline numbers and letters

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

Based on [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers#7045), is there a simple way to make the circles look exactly the same for numbers and all letters (i.e. size and placement)?

When one inserts an `a` in the circle, the node is drawn slightly lower than the node for a number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle, draw, inner sep=1pt, 
        minimum height=12pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
This is \circled{a} \circled{1} balloon.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Based on the answer by @koleygr and the post [circled letters: same size as uncircled letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267662/circled-letters-same-size-as-uncircled-letters), I find this solution the most pleasing and versatile:

```
\newcommand*{\circled}[2][]{\tikz[baseline=(C.base)]{
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (C) {\vphantom{1g}#2};
    \node[draw, circle, inner sep=3pt, yshift=1pt] 
        at (C.center) {\vphantom{1g}};}}
```

[image]

Comment: i'd try putting a `\strut` in with the letter or digit to guarantee that that's encircled always has the same height and depth.  (not tried; the default `\strut` may be a bit large, so an alternative could be `\vphantom{Xy}`.)

Comment: I edited my answer... You can write and select yours or make a combination of all and write an answer that contain all you need. It is ok to select your answer if it works better for your request and also it is better than letting selected an answer that doesn't really solves all parts of the problem.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89821/how-to-draw-a-solid-colored-circle, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123924/indexed-letters-inside-circles

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit after accepted:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle, draw, inner sep=1pt, 
        minimum height={\f@size*1.6},] (char) {\vphantom{WAH1g}#1};}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is \circled{a} \circled{1} balloon.

\noindent\foreach \letter in {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,V,U,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,.,/}
{%
\circled{\letter}\space%
}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Not really perfect because of different base on chars (but it is better from
the bellow answer)

Checking the same code in the document environment above with below definition of circled:

[image]

As you can see with previous (below) code the sizes change between small and capital letters.

**Old answer:**

A `\vphantom` in your definition will help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle, draw, inner sep=1pt, 
        minimum height=12pt] (char) {\vphantom{1g}#1};}}

\begin{document}
This is \circled{a} \circled{1} balloon.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: it appears that you're using a "one" in the `\vphantom` instead of a letter.  in some fonts (including, i believe, computer modern), the digits are not as tall as the tallest letters.  so using an "ell" instead of a "one" would shift the circle just slightly higher, but not so high as to adversely affect the letters with descenders.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @barbarabeeton... But I think the 1.6\f@size will take care of most cases. I think 1.75 or 1.8 would be better (as you can see in my output where capitals are in greater circle). Do you thing I have to place an H (or something) there instead of 1? I just kept "1" from my previous answer that is based on OP's question... But of course I can change it. I think I have to add that the taller letter has to be added there for different languages... What do you think?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I added some letters that I suppose that have enough height. Thanks again