# How do I put a circle around a symbol?

Tags: symbols

I am trying to put `\star` in a circle so I can use it on my paper. I could not find a proper way to do so. Is there a (simple) way of doing such a custom symbol?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! `$\bigostar$` from `MnSymbol`?

Comment: Oh amazing. I did look through some documentations but did not find that. Thanks!

Comment: i found this symbol in `The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List` , page 45.  it my sill be on CTAN. try with google ...

Comment: If you load `amsmath`, which is one of the most standard libraries, you could simply do `\textcircled{$\star$}` or `\textcircled{$*$}` . I hope this option will be appended to one of the answers...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scaling `\bigcirc` seems to yield a decent result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ostar}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\make@circled\star}}
\newcommand{\make@circled}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\smallbigcirc{#1}$\cr\hidewidth$\m@th#1#2$\hidewidth\cr}%
}
\newcommand{\smallbigcirc}[1]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.77778}{$\m@th#1\bigcirc$}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$x\ostar y$

$x\oplus y$

$\oplus\ostar$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some explanation of how this works would be helpful.

Comment: @PaulWintz It's a standard application of [`\ooalign`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22371/4427) and of [`\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/4427)

Answer (score 7):

You can use  the `\stackinset` command from `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine} 
\newcommand\oast{\stackMath\mathbin{\stackinset{c}{0ex}{c}{0ex}{\ast}{\bigcirc}}}

\begin{document}

 $ x \oast y$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you already are using `tikz` package or if you need other letters, symbols or numbers circled, or even if you want to change style or size in your symbol you can use my solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392188/120578).

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{tikz}
% #1 is a multiplier of fontsize for the minimum diameter of the circle
% #2 is the symbol to be circled.
\newcommand*\circled[2][1.6]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle, draw, inner sep=1pt, 
        minimum height={\f@size*#1},] (char) {\vphantom{WAH1g}#2};}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a \circled{*} and a \circled{$\star$} and a \circled{$\ast$}.

This is a \circled[1.2]{*} and a \circled[1.2]{$\star$} and a \circled[1.2]{$\ast$}

This is a \circled[0.8]{*} and a \circled[0.8]{$\star$} and a \circled[0.8]{$\ast$}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You can decrease more the size by removing the `\vphantom{WAH1g}` command

Comment: And you can remove the calc library, I guess.

Comment: Are you confusing the `calc` library and package? TikZ can do all sorts of calculations without the `calc` library, such as `width("X")` which has an analogon (I think it is `widthof`) in the `calc` *package*.

Comment: @marmot, I usually use `\tikzlibrary` calc in coordinate calculations for distances... I have heard for the `\widthof{}` but never used it before. The calculations here was simple for tikz but I read your message and thought that you mean it is not needed for the other cases I added. (I didn't used that calculation there)

Comment: But I did not see any place in your code in which the library calc was used. So I *guessed* you think it is necessary for some standard thingy. (BTW, I'd use tikz only if I wanted to put an ellipse around more than one star, in which case I'd use the fit library. Here a simple `\textcircled{$\star$}` `\textcircled{$*$}` which comes with `amsmath` will do. No tikz, no stackinset, no MnSymbol... perhaps want to add that to your answer?)

Comment: My answer is just a changed copy from the link... I was wandering if the OP needs one of these versions of circled star (because of the anchor) and then realized that he says `\star` and not star... and this is always centered. I had ready the code just for letters and copied. I think your idea can be an answer and deserve to be a separate (no packages).

Comment: Well, in the other answer, calc is not needed, too. Nor the complicated implementation of `minimum size`. So perhaps you want to clean up. And no, I am not going to write an answer here.