# Easy way to change character line thickness

Tags: symbols, contour

I am using some characters as reference marks. The ©, ℗ and ® are just what I need. However I need to use a circled dot as well. The circled dot I found, is of a much thinner line. Everything else seems fine though. Is there an easy way to make the line thicker? Please see my example below. I left the preamble pretty much as it is, so that any possible conflicts can be recognized.

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,fontsize=10pt,twoside,twocolumn,pagesize,DIV=15,headsepline,titlepage,openright,BCOR=8mm,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese,polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\languagechange}[3]{%
  %\wlog{Lang: #3}%
  \newcommand{#1}{}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{#1}{%
    \fontencoding{#2}\selectfont
    \csname otherlanguage*\endcsname{#3}%
  }%
}
\languagechange{\pl}{T1}{polish}
\languagechange{\vn}{T5}{vietnamese}

\newcommand{\xwzb}{{\small $\odot$}}
\newcommand{\xrzecz}{\textregistered}
\newcommand{\xczas}{\textcopyright}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[\pl abecadło] \vn xin chào
\item[\pl z pieca \xczas] \vn anh có khỏe không
\item[\pl spadło \xrzecz] \vn có gì mới không
\item[\pl i tyle \xwzb] \vn con chó
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: circled dot with thinner line]

Comment: Please, can you reduce your code in a minimal working example? Thank you. Related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451786/how-do-i-put-a-circle-around-a-symbol

Comment: @Sebastiano I reduced it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the package `contour`. It generates a (colored) contour around a given text  by placing copies of the text around the text itself.

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[paper=a5,fontsize=10pt,twoside,twocolumn,pagesize,DIV=15,headsepline,titlepage,openright,BCOR=8mm,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese,polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\languagechange}[3]{%
    %\wlog{Lang: #3}%
    \newcommand{#1}{}%
    \DeclareRobustCommand{#1}{%
        \fontencoding{#2}\selectfont
        \csname otherlanguage*\endcsname{#3}%
    }%
}
\languagechange{\pl}{T1}{polish}
\languagechange{\vn}{T5}{vietnamese}

\newcommand{\xwzb}{{\small $\odot$}}
\newcommand{\xrzecz}{\textregistered}
\newcommand{\xczas}{\textcopyright}

\usepackage[outline]{contour} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\xcxxx}{\contourlength{0.02em}\contour{black}{$\odot$}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{description}
        \item[\pl abecadło] \vn xin chào
        \item[\pl z pieca \xczas] \vn anh có khỏe không
        \item[\pl spadło \xrzecz] \vn có gì mới không
        \item[\pl i tyle \xwzb] \vn con chó
        \item[\pl i tyle \xcxxx] \vn tốt hơn rồi
    \end{description}

\end{document}
```