# Make tikz solution with smaller circled number work

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, numbering, fontsize, circles

I want to have circled numbers in my text and use the Ti*k*Z solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7045/156345). However, I want to make the circles and text a bit smaller so I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\begin{document}
Numbers aligned with the text:  \scriptsize{\circled{1}} end.
\end{document}
```

Unfortunatly, the `\scriptsize` seems to "leak" because all text after this command is small (in the text the "end" is also in scriptsize) although the curly parentesis are closed correctly.

How can I make this work without having the `\scriptsize` command "leak"?

Comment: The space between the number and the circle is given by the `inner sep` option. Just decrease it with for example `inner sep=.5pt`

Comment: `\scriptsize` does not take an argument. Try to enclose the text with changed font size in braces instead: `{\scriptsize some text}`. In this case, I would suggest `\circled{\scriptsize 1}`

Comment: Or allow for a parameter `\newcommand*\circled[2][]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,#1] (char) {#2};}}` and then do e.g. `\circled[scale=0.6]{1}` or `\circled[font=\scriptsize]{1}`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat that is of course better. It allows also to change other optiones (such as `inner sep`) if desired.

Comment: Take a look here too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392188/120578

Comment: Thank you all, I didn't even notice that scriptsize does not take an argument. Now it is working perfectly.

Comment: @SampleTime Even if `\scriptsize` has no argument, it doesn't change anything because you put the 8 in a group delimited by brackets. This group allows you to circle two-digit numbers such as 18 or 20...

Comment: @AndréC I guess you misunderstand the question. The original approach does work in a sense that the font size is changed (also inside the tikz-environment and the circle). But it is not changed back, or as the question says, `it leaks`. This is not really related to two-digit numbers or the circle size.

Comment: @Faekynn Yes, you're right. Once again, I did not understand well. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to correctly change the font size. `\scriptsize` does not take an argument and changes the font size for all text afterwards. If it is enclosed in braces (e.g., insinde the argument of `\circled{·}`), the font size change is only local.

Changed code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\begin{document}
Numbers aligned with the text:  \circled{\scriptsize1}  \circled{1} end.
\end{document}
```

And the output looks like this:

[image]

If you like to change the circle size, you can change value of the `inner sep` option as mentioned in the comment of AndréC.

Answer (score 2):

We can insert many things (texts, formulae, tables, images, etc) of LaTeX inside TikZ's `node` with plenty of options. One of the best option is `scale` that much flexible than LaTeX ones: `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge`, `\Huge`(maybe Stefan Kottwitz mentioned in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers/7045#7045)).

In summary, let us `scale` of `node` for this situation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[2]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
\node[circle,draw,scale=#2,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\begin{document}
Numbers aligned with the text:  \circled{1}{1}  \circled{\color{blue} 1}{1.5} end.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think changing the font size influences the stroke width of the text in a different way than just scaling the text with Ti*k*Z. (different sized letters are not just scaled versions of each other?)