# Undefined control sequences errors when compiling a PDF with TikZ in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

Thanks to [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392187/circled-inline-numbers-and-letters), I found a way to  circle numbers in the legend of a figure. Here is the command code :

```
\newcommand{\circled}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1.5pt](char){#1}}}
```

And here is my code :

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.75\linewidth}
        \centering
        \centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{./Introduction/images/tirf}}
        \centerline{\scriptsize{(a)}}\medskip
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{(Cis-)total internal reflection fluorescence microscope (TIRFM) diagram Specimen Evanescent wave range Cover slip Immersion oil Objective Emission beam (signal) Excitation beam.
    \circled{1} Specimen.
    \circled{2} Evanescent wave range.
    \circled{3} Cover slip.
    \circled{4} Immersion oil.
    \circled{5} Objective.
    \circled{6} Emission beam (signal).
    \circled{7} Excitation beam.
    Illustration created and released in public domain by Dawid Kulik.}
    \label{fig:tirf}
\end{figure}
```

Problem is, I get these errors when compiling.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \tikz@origsemi 
                               
l.1123 ...leased in public domain by Dawid Kulik.}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \tikz@origcolon 
                                
l.1123 ...leased in public domain by Dawid Kulik.}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@deactivatthings ...kz@nonactivecolon }\def |
                                                  {\tikz@nonactivebar }\def ...
l.1123 ...leased in public domain by Dawid Kulik.}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Argument of \tikz@style@parseA has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.1123 ...leased in public domain by Dawid Kulik.}
                                                  
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
(char.base)]{\node [shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt](char){1}} Specim\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \tikz@style@parseA was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.1123 ...leased in public domain by Dawid Kulik.}
                                                  
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

Strangely enough, everything looks fine in the PDF and the numbers are circled correctly. I have been investigating for hours and I still can't find out what is the problem. I tried removing and/or changing parameters in the `\newcommand`, searching for missing {}, moving the `\circled` commands outside the picture legend, explicitely adding the TikZ package in my main, etc. Nothing gave me a clue of what is happening, and I'm lost.

I thought of an package incompatibility but I have no idea which one could be causing a problem. FYI these are the ones I use :

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

The TikZ package seems to be already included in the template I am using.

Comment: Hi! Welcome! Please, why instead of posting snippets that we have to join (and incomplete: there is no `tikz` in your preamble!) don't you prepare a minimal, compilable example that shows the problem? It'll help a lot!

Comment: ...and see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers, especially (self-promotion!) https://ctan.org/pkg/circledsteps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you do not have posted an MWE (next time!), probably you just need to `\protect` your command (or use `circledsteps`!):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\newcommand{\circled}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1.5pt](char){#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \fbox{Fake figure}
    \caption{This has a \protect\circled{1}}
    \label{fig:lalla}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \fbox{Another fake figure}
    \caption{This has a (circledsteps) \Circled{1}}
    \label{fig:lilla}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Funny thing that you're this package author ;)

Comment: Yep --- ;-) that is the self-promotion thing in the comment above ;-)

Comment: Oh my god it worked!! Thanks a lot @Rmano :) I am not that used to StackOverflow-like platforms, I'll post a minimal working example next time. Thanks for your remarks and your help!

Comment: @FlatKos you're welcome! Happy LaTeXing!